# Android admob consuming more cpu

Tags: android, admob

Since I integrated the AdMob view on my app, the CPU usage of the app grose to 12% all the time. If i disable ads, then cpu usage become 0. Presently i integrated ads integrated through xml.

Answer (score 2):

It's most probably caused because Admob uses HTML - WebView to render Ads. Depending on device, it causes a looot of pain.

Try adding hardware acceleration on activity which displays the Ad.

```
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

Or the whole App:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

Or try some other configuration more specific:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html